# How can I add a field to a MS Access 2002 form which relates to another table?

Tags: microsoft-access

I have a *MS Access 2002* form which basically provides text boxes to manipulate records in a table called `Materials`. I also have another table called `MaterialCosting` which has a column `MaterialID` which links it to the `Materials` table which also has a column `MaterialID`. What I am trying to do is to add a text box to this form which reads and writes to a field of `MaterialCosting` named `outerCarton`.

Here are my failed attempts:

1. Right click on the form, Choose *properties*, and in *data->Record source*, enter an SQL query that joins the two tables (`SELECT * FROM Materials AS M INNER JOIN MaterialCosting AS C ON C.MaterialID = M.MaterialID`). Then simply put the name of the required column (`outerCarton`) in the text box's *control source*.
2. In the text box's *control source*, put `DLookup("[outerCarton]", "[MaterialCosting]", "MaterialCosting.MaterialID = Materials.MaterialID")`

Both of these had the same result: the text box would end up with `#Name?` in it and do nothing.

How can I make this work?

**UPDATE**

The form's properties
[image: Form's properties]
The control's properties
[image]

Comment: You said *"add a text box which reads and writes to a column"*, but you are using a lookup in the control source box. Are you adding just a blank text box which data will be entered into? Or are you trying to add a combo-box for data to be selected from?

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm trying to add a text box which will display (and allow me to edit) a specific field of `MaterialCosting`.

Comment: What happens when you simply use `outerCarton` as the Record Source? If the tables are already linked as you say, you should be able to use it without putting a query in the text box.

Comment: What SQL query did you use in #1?

Comment: @CharlieRB Simply using `outerCarton` as the Record Source is what I do in #1. I edited it to add the SQL I use for that as well. It results in the field having `#Name?` in it.

Comment: Am I explaining my problem correctly?

Comment: I am pretty sure I understand what you are trying to do. What happpens in #1 above without putting `outerCarton` in the text box's control field. Does the SQL inner join work at that point?

Comment: @CharlieRB How can I tell if the inner join works or not?

Comment: If you were able to select `outerCarton` from the control's record source drop down, the SQL query is working. Is there any way you can put a screen shot of the form and control properties on here? I think you are close to this working.

Comment: @CharlieRB I added screenshots

Comment: Let's try this from a different angle to troubleshoot a little bit. Make the `MaterialCosting` table the form's control source (without SQL). Then add `outerCarton` as the text box's control source. Does it still give the error?

Comment: Hmm, actually, selecting from MaterialCosting only results in an 'ODBC --Call Failed' error... And if I don't use SQL but only write MaterialCosting, then I get a compile error: object library feature not supported, and "DBForm =" gets highlighted in this VBA line: "Set DBForm = Me" which appears in a procedure called "Private Sub Form_Load()". Any clue what all this means? Sorry for the lack of formatting, I can't find the back tick on this keyboard..

Comment: Yikes. The hope was it would at least work for that control, not get worse. I didn't realize there was VBA code running on loading of the form. So, the form worked properly before adding the text box, right?

Comment: Yes, the form wors as long as I have `Materials` in the form's Control Source.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate the `#Name?` you are seeing. It appears its just an SQL statement issue in how you called the data.

To correct it, I had to do the following;

1. For the FORM Record Source place this SQL; `SELECT Materials.*, MaterialCosting.* FROM Materials INNER JOIN MaterialCosting ON Materials.MaterialID = MaterialCosting.MaterialID;`
2. Now you should be able to select `outerCarton` from the drop down for Record Source of the text field.
3. Switch to form view and see if you can select records and change the value.

Let me know how that works.

Comment: I don't see the difference between what you're doing and what I'm doing. I was already selecting everything (*). Anyways, I tried your variant and it made no difference. I am indeed able to select `outerCarton`from the drop down when I use an inner join, but I still get `#Name?`. What does `#Name?` mean anyways?

Comment: `#Name?` indicates the name used for the control source is not valid. This can be caused by several things. Here is a [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/i-see-name-displayed-in-a-control-HA001181447.aspx) to more information about that.

Comment: By chance, do both tables have a field named `outerCarton`?

Comment: No, only MaterialCosting has that field. I'll have a look at that link and ask my employer if I can post a screenshot and then I'll get back to you.