# Can Access display a related field on a data entry form?

Tags: microsoft-access

Let's say I'm building an Access database to hold recipes and calculate the cost of those recipes. I need a table of recipes, a table of possible ingredients, and a table of recipe line items.

Each ingredient's cost is stored in the Ingredients table, along with the unit of measurement. For example, we might store an ingredient "Hamburger" with a measurement unit of "ounces" and cost of $0.25 per ounce.

```
RECIPES    INGREDIENTS        RECIPELINES
--------   -------------      -------------
ID         ID                 ID
Name       Name               RecipeID
           MeasurementUnit    IngredientID
           CostPerUnit        Quantity
```

I'm creating a subform to add recipe lines. I want to allow input of the Quantity field, but I also want to display the ingredient's measurement unit. In other words, I want the form to look like this:

```
RECIPE FORM
  ID:   [ 5 ]
  Name: [ Guacamole ]

  Recipe line items: (this is the subform)

      INGREDIENT           AMT     UNIT
      ----------------------------------
      [ Hass Avocado   ] [ 2.0 ] [ EA  ]
      [ Red Onion      ] [ 0.5 ] [ CUP ]
      [ Habanero Chile ] [ 2.0 ] [ EA  ]
```

Once the user enters an ingredient name (a combo box over the IngredientID field), I want to display the measurement unit so the user knows if they're typing in ounces, cups, pounds, or what. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote out the entire question, then Super User pointed me to [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/388232/how-can-i-add-a-field-to-a-ms-access-2002-form-which-relates-to-another-table) that incidentally had the answer I needed.

On the form itself, change the Record Source to be a query rather than a table. In this case:

```
SELECT RecipeLines.*, Ingredients.MeasurementUnit
FROM Ingredients
INNER JOIN RecipeLines ON Ingredients.ID = RecipeLines.IngredientID;
```

Then, MeasurementUnit becomes a selectable Control Source on a text box. By disabling the text box, it becomes a view-only display.